# How to use loadgraph and fetchgraph from JPA 2.1 on Query DSL 4

Tags: hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, querydsl, jpa-2.1

Environment:

```
org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.2.14.Final
org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:5.0.1.Final
org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:6.0.7.Final

org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:2.0.5.RELEASE
org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:2.0.5.RELEASE

com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:4.1.4
com.querydsl:querydsl-core:4.1.4
com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:4.1.4
```

Entity:

```
@Getter
@DynamicUpdate
@Entity
@Table(
    name = TABLE_NAME,
    uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {CODE_COLUMN_NAME}, name = CATEGORY_CODE_UNIQUE),
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {NAME_COLUMN_NAME}, name = CATEGORY_NAME_UNIQUE)
    })
public class Category extends Auditable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
    @Column(name = CODE_COLUMN_NAME, nullable = false, updatable = false, unique = true)
    private Long code;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = NAME_COLUMN_NAME, nullable = false, unique = true, length = NAME_COLUMN_MAX_LENGTH)
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = PARENT_ID_COLUMN_NAME)
    private Category parent;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = TABLE_NAME, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<CategoryCountry> categoriesCountries = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = TABLE_NAME, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<CategoryTranslation> categoryTranslations = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

CategoryRepository with JPA 2.1:

```
public Category findByIdEager(final Long id) {
    final EntityGraph categoryEntityGraph = createCategoryEntityGraph();

    final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

    final CriteriaQuery<Category> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Category.class);

    final Root<Category> root = criteriaQuery.from(Category.class);
    criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("id"), id));

    return categoryTypedQuery(criteriaQuery, categoryEntityGraph).getSingleResult();
}


private EntityGraph createCategoryEntityGraph() {
    final EntityGraph categoryEntityGraph = entityManager.createEntityGraph(Category.class);
    categoryEntityGraph.addSubgraph("categoryTranslations");
    categoryEntityGraph.addSubgraph("categoriesCountries");

    return categoryEntityGraph;
}


private TypedQuery<Category> categoryTypedQuery(final CriteriaQuery<Category> criteriaQuery, final EntityGraph categoryEntityGraph) {
    final TypedQuery<Category> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    typedQuery.setHint("javax.persistence.loadgraph", categoryEntityGraph);

    return typedQuery;
}
```

CategoryRepository with Query DSL:

```
public Category findByIdEager(final Long id) {

    QCategory category = QCategory.category;
    QCategoryTranslation categoryTranslation = QCategoryTranslation.categoryTranslation;
    QCategoryCountry categoryCountry = QCategoryCountry.categoryCountry;

    return from(category)
        .leftJoin(categoryCountry).on(categoryCountry.category.id.eq(category.id))
        .leftJoin(categoryTranslation).on(categoryTranslation.category.id.eq(category.id))
        .where(category.id.eq(id))
        .fetchOne();
}
```

CategoryService:

```
@Transactional
public getFindByIdEager() { ... }
```

**Question**:

Using JPA 2.1 approach, when the `CategoryService.getFindByIdEager` with a `@Transactional`
the category is retrieved with all countries and translations already fetched but with **duplicate rows**.

But, when using QueryDSL approach, the service `CategoryService` return the Category entity but the countries and translations are not fetched. And I end up having the exception `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException`.

DataBase - Category Entity:

```
  ID: 2
  NAME: Sport
  PARENT: { ID: 1, NAME: Shoes}
  COUNTRIES: [NG, EG]
  TRANSLATIONS: [Shoes_Sport_1, Shoes_Sport_2, Shoes_Sport_3]
```

Response using JPA 2.1

```
  ID: 2
  NAME: Sport
  PARENT: { ID: 1, NAME: Shoes}
  COUNTRIES: [NG, EG]
  TRANSLATIONS: [Shoes_Sport_1, Shoes_Sport_1, Shoes_Sport_2, Shoes_Sport_2, Shoes_Sport_3, Shoes_Sport_3]
```

Response using QueryDSL

```
  ID: 2
  NAME: Sport
  PARENT: { ID: 1, NAME: Shoes}
  COUNTRIES: `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException`
  TRANSLATIONS: `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException`
```

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use fetchJoin() rather than leftJoin().

Comment: using fetchJoin() implies duplicate rows.